# htaccess redirect .htm and .php pages to extensionless

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm rebuilding an existing website which includes .htm extensions in php.
I have the following in my .htaccess file so that .php files are extensionless but how do I redirect any potential .htm pages to the extentionless .php page?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(.htm)?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't work and it messes up my php to extensionless rewrite. Do I need to redirect the .htm pages to .php then extensionless?